# How to efficiently divide list of variables into other variables

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm looking to efficiently divide a list of columns into specific columns.

```
dict <- tibble(
  numerator_cols = letters[1:4],
  denominator_cols = rep(c('e', 'f'), 2)
)

df <- tibble(
  a = rnorm(10),
  b = rnorm(10),
  c = rnorm(10),
  d = rnorm(10),
  e = rnorm(10),
  f = rnorm(10)
)
```

Here, columns in the numerator_cols dictionary should be divided by the columns in the denominator_cols.

Comment: Ideally completely in the tidyverse. It would be a tibble.

Answer (score 0):

```r
library(dplyr)

dict <- tibble(
  numerator_cols = letters[1:4],
  denominator_cols = rep(c('e', 'f'), 2)
)

df <- tibble(
  a = rnorm(10),
  b = rnorm(10),
  c = rnorm(10),
  d = rnorm(10),
  e = rnorm(10),
  f = rnorm(10)
)

result <- df[,dict$numerator_cols] / df[,dict$denominator_cols]  

names(result) <- paste(dict$numerator_cols ,"/", dict$denominator_cols)
result
#>          a / e       b / f       c / e      d / f
#> 1   -1.6028126  -0.7627333   2.9986502  1.2437091
#> 2    1.3005748   4.3801949   1.0315203 -0.5891400
#> 3    0.3158292  -0.1671003  -0.9193041 -0.9772828
#> 4    1.1722359   0.9557980  -0.8302960  1.0982044
#> 5   -0.7263442 -22.3924580   0.3575551  7.5041730
#> 6    1.2658805  -0.7155377   0.3626143 -0.9062837
#> 7    3.8941807   0.5168030   7.5230873  0.9622144
#> 8    0.9460343  -1.9523333   0.1964858  2.3458176
#> 9   -1.8698886  -0.7841627  -0.1769269  1.1056992
#> 10 -10.1486759  -0.9166868 -15.3601121 -1.3975514
```

<sup>Created on 2023-03-13 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Here's a tidyverse solution with `map2`:

```
library(tidyverse)

map2(dict[[1]], dict[[2]], \(x, y) tibble("{x}/{y}" := df[[x]] / df[[y]])) |> 
  list_cbind()

# A tibble: 10 × 4
     `a/e`    `b/f`   `c/e`   `d/f`
     <dbl>    <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>
 1  0.807    4.83     1.54    1.68 
 2  1.11   -12.6      1.05   10.3  
 3 -1.23    -9.35     0.811 -20.9  
 4  0.0325   0.0809  -0.336   0.642
 5  0.107    2.46    -0.517  -3.64 
 6 -1.53     1.18     1.50    0.454
 7 -1.14    -0.321   -2.08   -0.358
 8  2.71    -3.36    -0.329  -0.106
 9 -0.881    5.66    -1.46   -2.47 
10  5.35    -2.19   -15.0    -1.76
```

Another option, although note [`map_dfc` is superseded](https://purrr.tidyverse.org/reference/map_dfr.html):

```
map_dfc(dict[[1]], \(x) df[[x]]) / map_dfc(dict[[2]], \(y) df[[y]])
```

Note: Use `set.seed(123)` to reproduce this `df`.

Answer (score 0):

Using `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr) # version >= 1.1.0
df %>%
   transmute(across(all_of(dict$numerator_cols),
    ~ .x/pick(dict$denominator_cols[match(cur_column(), 
     dict$numerator_cols)])[[1]],
    .names = "{.col}/{dict$denominator_cols[match(.col, dict$numerator_cols )]}"))
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 10 × 4
     `a/e`   `b/f`  `c/e`   `d/f`
     <dbl>   <dbl>  <dbl>   <dbl>
 1 -1.10     1.70   2.22  -4.21  
 2 -0.328   -0.380  3.67  -1.94  
 3 -0.323    0.207 -1.46   0.0458
 4 -0.261    2.02  -0.569  1.62  
 5 -0.260    0.596  3.48   0.623 
 6 -2.92    -0.943 -8.63  -0.695 
 7  0.386   -1.19   0.950  0.0424
 8  0.665  -19.6   -0.435 10.2   
 9  0.728   -1.10  -0.361  0.0559
10  0.0628  -0.551  0.172 -1.03
```